# Can't receive notifictations from FCM on iOS

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a server (Java) that sends messages with Google's FCM.
On Android it works fine I can receive the notifications, but for some reason on iOS it doesn't.

Here is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
import GoogleMobileAds

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate    {
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "my_message_type"

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        registerToFirestoreMessaging(application)
                     
        return true
    }

    func registerToFirestoreMessaging(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
            if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
                print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
            }
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        print("User Info: \(userInfo)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
                print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
            }
        print("User Info: \(userInfo)")
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
        #if PROD_BUILD
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
        print("APNs prod token")
        #else
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
        print("APNs sandbox token")
        #endif
    }
}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print("User Info: \(userInfo)")
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
    
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
  }
}


extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
      object: nil,
      userInfo: dataDict)
  }
}
```

I have Push Notifications and remote notifications in Background Modes in my capabilities.
I've tried to use this code with swizzling enabled and disabled. It doesn't makes any change.

Thanks for reading. Any help will be welcomed!

Comment: Hi! Have you uploaded your APNS certificates/Auth Token on the FCM console?

Comment: What does 'revice' mean in English?

Comment: That's a needle in a haystack.  What makes you think it's a coding issue?  What does 'on iOS it doesn't' mean?  How does it not work?

Comment: Sorry, revice was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: I've uploaded the APNS key to the FCM console. The server and the FCM API both claim that the message was sent successfully, but I don't receive it on my iphone.... The code is exactly the same as Google's documentation, and I think I've done all the steps. I also used this https://www.raywenderlich.com/20201639-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-ios-push-notifications

Comment: @OmerBenedek Looks good till `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)`. What happens inside `messaging(_:didReceiveRegistrationToken:)`? Do you get `fcmToken` here? Can you show us one token as example? What do you do with it? Do you find this in your [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)? Can you send a test message to this token via Firebase Cloud Messaging service?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I'm uploading the token elsewhere (on the signup page). I'm able to send a message view FCM using the "send test message" button, but not using the way described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message?authuser=0#send_a_notification_message

Comment: @OmerBenedek So you upload the token during signup; Why Signup? What about after login? Also... the controllers that observe `Notification.Name("FCMToken")`, do they exist in memory for them to react to this notification & upload the token? Could there be a race condition here? Do you find this token uploaded in your database? Finally... using that `fcmToken`, you should be able to send a test message from [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/_/notification/compose)?

Comment: @staticVoidMan, the FCM token rarely changes, so for the sake of testing I assumed that it stays the same (not a great idea, will be fixed when it's working). I'm not observing the FCMToken notification, so I can delete it (it's just a code I copied from Google). The fcmToken that I'm getting here is the same as the one stored in my db, and when I'm trying to send a test notification using the link you provided it just doesn't work... Maybe I'm missing a step (how does it know what devices are iOS and what are Android, idk...).

Comment: @OmerBenedek What about the project settings [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/_). Is the server key correct? Are the APNs Authentication Key or Certificates still valid?

Comment: @staticvoidman Yes, I'm using APNs Authentication key and it's valid and correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications without title and body aren't supposed to show in the notification pane. I was expecting to see a notification in the notification pane, but the notifications the server was sending are silent notifications.
In order to accept those notifications, you must implement `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in your `AppDelegate.swift`.

Here is how I did it:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // In my userInfo is the messageID of the notification
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            handleSilentNotification(messageType: messageID as! String)
        }
        // I'm not using swizzling, so I have to notify FCM that a message was received.
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

After that I'm sending a local notification and it works as intended.
Thanks to anyone that helped!